# when we are connected with spring mvc or spring boot how to check type of driver?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, driver, spring-jdbc

when we are connected with spring mvc or spring boot how to check type of driver?
how to connect with type 1 driver or type 2 driver or type 3 driver?
By default I guess type4 driver is executed when we run application.properties file of spring?

Answer (score 1):

To get the driver you can do this:

```
System.out.println(dataSource.getConnection().getMetaData().getDriverName());
```